# Impersonating userName not App Pool MVC2

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory

Earlier, I asked a question about getting windows active directory information from the user in a MVC2 website (using windows authentication) and passing it too a webService so that the webservice can be used... The webservice uses the user's username to get information back by the way... In that same webservice, an Oracle Database will be called, but with a set username not related to the user just FYI...
Well, it kindof works.  It definitely works for me, but some other members of my team that do not have the permissions that I do, are having issues...

Does anyone now of any good tutorials dealing with this subject... I will expand upon my question in a second.  Have to run to a quick meeting.

Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx) has a good overview of impersonation versus delegation in Windows. ASP.NET by default always uses AppPool identity for a thread's security context. Impersonation is limited to accessing only local resources to the machine executing the code. Delegation is required to allow access to remote/network resources (the WCF service). Here is [a good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx) on how impersonation & delegation work in WCF.